# The set $5^{-\infty}\mathbb{Z}$ is a colimit

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, limits-colimits

I am trying to understand why the set of rational numbers whose denominators are powers of $5$, $5^{-\infty}\mathbb{Z}$, is a colimit. Specifically, why is $5^{-\infty}\mathbb{Z}$ the colimit of the diagram $$\mathbb{Z}\longrightarrow5^{-1}\mathbb{Z}\longrightarrow5^{-2}\mathbb{Z}\longrightarrow\cdots$$

I'm not sure what the maps to $5^{-\infty}\mathbb{Z}$ are. They can't be inclusion, or else we won't get commutativity. What am I missing?

I imagine the arrows above are given by division by $5$, and maybe the maps to the limit are multiplication by $5$?

Comment: In which category you take colimit?

Comment: @FabioLucchini It wasn't specified. This is an example in Vakil. I assume rings.

Comment: Perhaps the maps above are division by $5$ and the maps to the limit are multiplication by $5$?

Comment: $5^{-1}\Bbb Z$ is not a ring, but an abelian group; what's wrong by taking group inclusions?

Comment: @FabioLucchini Because if $n\in\mathbb{Z}\hookrightarrow 5^{-\infty}\mathbb{Z}$, then $n\mapsto n/5$ in $5^{-1}\mathbb{Z}$, which then maps to $n/5$ in $ 5^{-\infty}\mathbb{Z}$ under inclusion, and so the diagram does not commute.

Comment: Cannot be $\Bbb Z\hookrightarrow 5^{-1}\Bbb Z\hookrightarrow\cdots$?

Comment: The colimit of $\Bbb Z\xrightarrow{x\mapsto x/5}5^{-1}\Bbb Z\to\cdots$ is $\Bbb Z$ because every arrow in this diagram is a group isomorphism.

Comment: @ponchan: I think the map $\mathbb Z \to 5^{-1}\mathbb Z$ is $n \mapsto n$, not $n \mapsto \frac{n}{5}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\require{AMScd}$First note that the colimit of the diagram (of sets or abelin groups)
$$\Bbb Z\xrightarrow{x\mapsto x/5}5^{-1}\Bbb Z\xrightarrow{x\mapsto x/5}5^{-2}\Bbb Z\to\cdots$$
is $\Bbb Z$ because we have a commutative diagram
\begin{CD}
\Bbb Z@>x\mapsto x/5>>5^{-1}\Bbb Z@>x\mapsto x/5>>5^{-2}\Bbb Z@>>>\cdots\\
@|@Vx\mapsto 5xVV@Vx\mapsto 5^2xVV\\
\Bbb Z@=\Bbb Z@=\Bbb Z@=\cdots
\end{CD}
where each arrow is an isomorphism (of sets or abelian groups).

On the other hand, the colimit of the diagram
$$\Bbb Z\hookrightarrow5^{-1}\Bbb Z\hookrightarrow 5^{-2}\Bbb Z\hookrightarrow\cdots$$
is
$$5^{-\infty}\Bbb Z=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}5^{-n}\Bbb Z\tag 1$$
because if $M$ is an abelian group and $\varphi_n:5^{-n}\Bbb Z\to M$ for $n\in\Bbb N$ is a cocone of homomorphisms, then $\varphi_n|5^{-m}\Bbb Z=\varphi_m$ for every $m<n$.
By $(1)$, the map
\begin{align}
&5^{-n}x\mapsto\varphi_n(5^{-n}x)&&(x\in\Bbb Z)
\end{align}
defines the required homomorphism $\varphi:5^{-\infty}\Bbb Z\to M$.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: $5^{-n}\Bbb{Z}$ here means $\{5^{-n} x \mid x \in \Bbb{Z}\} \subseteq \Bbb{Q}$. The arrow $5^{-n}\Bbb{Z} \to 5^{-n-1}\Bbb{Z}$ is the inclusion function $x \mapsto x$ (a multiple of $1/5$ is also a multiple of $1/25$ etc.). The [colimit construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_limit) gives that the elements  of the colimit are represented by finite sequences $(x_1, \ldots x_n)$ of integers with $x_n \neq 0$  (or $n = 1$ and $x_n = 0$) under an equivalence relations that means each such sequence can be identified with $x_n/5^n$.